# iOS - retrieving latest receipt after subscription auto renewd

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I would like to offer a monthly subscription (as In App Purchase) to my users. When the user buys a subscription a receipt is stored on the device with an expiration date one month after purchase date. My question is how i should retrieve a new receipt after this month is passed and the subscription auto renewed?

What i am doing now is to perform refresh receipt using SKReceiptRefreshRequest when i recognize that there is an expired receipt on the device. The problem with this method is that it triggers the "Sign in to iTunes Store" popup. I am testing the app using sandbox users.

Comment: What are you selling?  Depending on what you are selling and the limited info I have, i'm guessing you are going to have to use in-app purchases otherwise you will be rejected.  Unless you are selling a physical product, you have to use in-app purchases so Apple can get their cut.  I can maybe help out a little more if i know if it is a physical product or not.

Comment: I added this info to the original message now. I am using IAP for this purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Managing subscriptions with In-App Purchase](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012-308/) minute 21:00 exactly.

This happens automatically when user opens your app. The implemented delegate will receive any waiting new receipts.

Comment: So is it a bug with sand box users? Although it renews for 5 times, i don't receive a new transcation

Comment: No the sandbox works as the live server. Maybe you should provide some code. And where do you set ur delegate?

Comment: I set the delegate when the app loads. I set it in a singleton class that is initialized using Typhoon when app loads

Comment: Also tried moving the set delegate to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions of AppDelegate but the result is the same - i don't receive the a new transaction when subscription is auto renewed. If i try to restore receipts than i receive a new receipt.

Comment: Sorry if this is covered in the video (can't watch it right now), but how do you know if the subscription is still valid if the user uninstalls the app, or does not open it for a month?  In this case, do I need to store and re-verify the receipt on the server every month?  A subscription gives the user access to a unique product, that while the sub is active, only they have access to.  However, I want to free up the resource if the sub expires.  Is this just a job for cron?

Comment: @ErikSapir, _In the testing environment, and auto-renewable subscriptions renew a maximum of six times per day._ [Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-SW8) i guess you should create new user every time.